# Running out of memory, only on the server - not locally though

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, foreach, out-of-memory

I have a custom drupal module that i am working on.

i've been working on this for 2 days now and i narrowed it down to this one function that simulates a SQL LEFT JOIN.

```
foreach ($merge as $remove => $right) {
 foreach ($original as $index => $left) {
   foreach ($on as $from_key => $to_key) {
     if (!isset($original[$index][$from_key])
       || !isset($right[$to_key])
       || $original[$index][$from_key] != $right[$to_key]) {
       continue 2;
     }
   }
   $original[$index] = array_merge($left, $right);
   unset($merge[$remove]);
 }
}
```

i put some watchdogs around this foreach loops and i found out that, locally, this foreach loop only adds anywhere from 2MB to 50Mb depending on the size of the arrays.

Everything was great until i deployed it onto the test server where i got an "out of memory" error. When i looked at the logs, i found that, the very same foreach group was using anywhere from 100Mb to 2Gb or memory depending on the size of the arrays...

i even tried to manually call the garbage collector but that only gave me 2-5 Mb back each time, which didnt help much...

i even compared the php.ini files from my local machine and the test server and the only differences are that on the test server, the `memory_limit is set to -1` but then inside both of the settings.php files, that is changes to `ini_set('memory_limit', '3072M');`... another difference i found was that on the test server the `session.gc_probability = 0` while locally it was 1, but then the same thing happens inside the settings.php files: both files change it to 1 :
`ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);`

and the settings.php files are pretty much the same

**UPDATE**: 
At @MokeyZeus' request, here is the entire function, where original is the 2D array to the left of the "join", $merge is the 2D array to the right of the "join" and $on is an array with the filter on which the 2 arrays join (the SQL ON)

`function fulfillment_array_join(array $original, array $merge, array $on) {
  if (!is_array($on)) {
    $on = array($on);
  }
  $current = (memory_get_usage(TRUE)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
  $peak = (memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
  watchdog('fulfillment',
    'BEFORE foreach loop - inside fulfillment_array_join.
    Current memory: %current.
    Peak memory: %peak.',
    array('%current' => $current, '%peak' => $peak),
    WATCHDOG_INFO
  );
  foreach ($merge as $remove => $right) {
    foreach ($original as $index => $left) {
      foreach ($on as $from_key => $to_key) {
        if (!isset($original[$index][$from_key])
          || !isset($right[$to_key])
          || $original[$index][$from_key] != $right[$to_key]) {
          continue 2;
        }
      }
      $original[$index] = array_merge($left, $right);
      unset($merge[$remove]);
    }
  }
  $current = (memory_get_usage(TRUE)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
  $peak = (memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
  watchdog('fulfillment',
    'AFTER foreach loop - inside fulfillment_array_join.
    Current memory: %current.
    Peak memory: %peak.',
    array('%current' => $current, '%peak' => $peak),
    WATCHDOG_INFO
  );
  gc_collect_cycles();
  $current = (memory_get_usage(TRUE)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
  $peak = (memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
  watchdog('fulfillment',
    'GC_COLLECT - inside fulfillment_array_join.
    Current memory: %current.
    Peak memory: %peak.',
    array('%current' => $current, '%peak' => $peak),
    WATCHDOG_INFO
  );
  return $original;
}`

and here is the way i call the function:

`$filter_dss_osa = array(
    'OrderId' => 'Order ID',
    'OfferId' => 'Offer ID',
    'ShipQty' => 'Ordered Quantity',
  );
  $drop_ship_offers_processing = fulfillment_array_join($drop_ship_shipment_datasheet, $offer_sales_analysis_by_shipdate_datasheet, $filter_dss_osa);`

Comment: what is all these variables values, for example `$original` is not correlated to the first loop.  I would expect if it was nested it would be.

Comment: where do these arrays come from?

Comment: How large is the initial `$merge` locally vs on the server? Also, why is a PHP function simulating a SQL LEFT JOIN? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: How much memory is being consumed right before the `foreach ($merge as $remove => $right) {`? Try `echo memory_get_usage();`

Comment: I am simulating a SQL LEFT JOIN because i am dealing with php arrays. These php arrays are the result of a ton of logic and processing once i get some initial data from the DB. A client's UI input has a lot of weight on the logic that creates these huge arrays as well, so i can not keep them in a sql table.

@MonkeyZeus, see updated post that contains the entire function i had

Comment: same php version server/local? which one anyway? What are the measures (hundreds or thousand of entries to combine)?
Arrays in PHP use tons of overhead. Read this: 
https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: @LarsStegelitz i am joining 4 arrays: 
oo 2006 x 138 (2006 rows, 138 columns)
ps 1659 x 197
db 414 x 92
ss 414 x 20

i read that article while i was researching this issue, but the issue is that locally it's just fine, but remotely it goes crazy...

Locally: `PHP Version => 5.5.22`
Remotely: `PHP Version => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17`

Comment: Can you please answer my question with `echo memory_get_usage();`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, 
remotely i have these numbers
ps_db   530 - 781 (MB memory used before - after)
ps_db_ss   781 - 1094
ps_db_ss_ra  1086 - 2473
ps_db_ss_ra_oo 2464 - dies
............ 
now locally: 
ps_db   530 - 535 (MB memory used before - after)
ps_db_ss   535 - 545
ps_db_ss_ra  545 - 565
ps_db_ss_ra_oo 565 - 570

Comment: install php 5.5.9 on you local machine and observe. if possible install 5.5.22 onto the server.